# How do you detect from a service that the app process has closed?

Tags: java, android, service

I have an Android app that consists of a Service and various activities. When the app starts, the Service is started with startService(Intent service). Various activities (but not all activities) bind to the Service and send/receive messages from it. The service should be alive while the app is in the foreground on any activity or in the background, but should end when the entire app is closed (i.e. user swipes the app from Recent Apps screen).

How do I determine from the Service (which currently never stops running until you manually stop it on the device) that the app process has ended so that I can then stop the service?

Comment: You could check for an static variable for null on your activities within your service, so if the variable is null the activity already finished

Comment: please, don't do this. it leads to the very bad code design and issues that you can't predict, starting from memory leaks.

Comment: @Artyomcool have realized now that the issue I'm having is actually related to Bluetooth Low Energy on Android. Some devices filter advertising packets, while others get flooded with them. When running my app on the latter, the BLE discovery scan never ends even after closing the app, force stopping the service, uninstalling the app, even turning Bluetooth off and back on...

Answer (score 2):

Since the service is hopefully part of the same process as everything else, it will not be notified that the process has terminated, because the process will be terminated, and so the service's code will no longer be running. There is no advance warning of a process being terminated.

If for some reason you put the service in a separate process, please reconsider that.

Also, note that `IntentService` is not really designed for use with the binding pattern. An `IntentService` is designed for transactional work, performed on a background thread. The use of `IntentService` for anything else is a major code smell.

Comment: Oddly enough, after the app/process stops (0 processes and 1 service) the service's code IS running. It continues to perform its actions such as scanning for BLE devices, pairing to devices in range, etc

Comment: @D.Wescotty while you got the answer from the honourable person himself, you can check the current activity stack and see if any of your activities is on top or running, if not, stop self.

Comment: @D.Wescotty: "after the app/process stops (0 processes and 1 service) the service's code IS running" -- by definition, that is not possible. If you have no process, your code is not running. Now, what could be happening is that if you returned something like `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`, is that Android might be restarting your process, though it should show up there. `START_NOT_STICKY` is probably a better choice.

Comment: another thing could happen - proccess just wasn't stopped

Answer (score 0):

Just don't start service manually. When you bind it from activities it starts and shuts down automatically.

Comment: The issue with this is that not all Activities in the app bind to the service. It should be running throughout the life of the app whether or not the current activity is bound to it. It should only stop processing when the app is closed in entirety

Comment: the services are not designed in this way, so you can't do this without durty hacks

Comment: and you should also realize that swiping app from recents not neccessary stops the proccess.

Comment: @Artyomcool: AFAIK, it does, with the exception of foreground services on Android 4.3 and below. If you have evidence to the contrary, can you post a link?

Comment: here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19987/what-actually-happens-when-you-swipe-an-app-out-of-the-recent-apps-list/20663#20663 and also the topic contains an answer for the original question